# Touchpad driver missing after windows 10 installation in acer E3-111-290X

Tags: os-kernel

I was asked by a friend to help installing windows 10 in an acer E3-111-290X that was previously running windows 7, but after installing windows 10 the touchpad stopped working.I've tried several solutions such as synaptics drivers but didn't work.
Anyone with an answer or knowing a better place to get the solution for the problem, help please!

Comment: This question is blatantly off-topic on CS.SE. Please review [the tour](http://cs.stackexchange.com/tour), as well as [what's on-topic](http://cs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [off-topic](http://cs.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) here. I'm going to flag to move this to a more topical SE site.

Comment: This is grossly off-topic here. This site is about **computer science**, please read the full site name before posting and check the [tour](/tour) and [help center](/help/on-topic) if you have any doubts. Furthermore the question is not answerable as is, you would need to give more information about what stopped working (does Windows still see a peripheral or not, etc.) and say what “several solutions” you tried.

Answer (score 1):

According to this [link](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/insider_wintp-insider_devices/touchpad-issue-with-windows-10-technical-preview/a71f84c9-c4b7-43b8-9c07-405dfa1b6a85), you may have more luck installing the Synaptics driver from the Acer website in compatibility mode.

Comment: Please don't answer off-topic questions before they are migrated to a more topical site. (This reduces the overall quality of the site's content and is generally seen as bad practice on StackExchange network sites).